# Javascript - Looping through classes and adding functions

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm currently trying to create an HTML5 Canvas game and I want to be able to attach functions to buttons that activate when clicked. I can do this for unique functions but I'm struggling to find a way to do it when looping through many buttons with a predefined function.

I've created an example to show what I've tried so far:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ra1rb74w/1/

```
// The class that we want to create an array of
myClass = function() {
    this.aFunction;
};

myClass.prototype = {
    // Add a new function to this class
    addFunction: function (newFunction) {
        this.aFunction = newFunction;
    },

    // Use the current function
    useFunction: function () {
        if (this.aFunction != null) {
            this.aFunction;
        }
    }
};

// The base function we will use in the classes
var baseFunction = function(x) { console.log(x); }

// Create the array of classes
var myClasses = [];

// Add 10 classes to the array and add a function to each of them
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    myClasses.push(new myClass());
    myClasses[x].addFunction(baseFunction(x));
}

// Use the function in the first class
myClasses[0].useFunction();
```

You can see that all the functions get triggered which I don't want, and the useFunction() function doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Wow. At first - addFunction expect function as param ( as i understand ) but you'l push undefined there ( as result of calling baseFunction) . And useFunction - didn't call aFunction ( but it should is i think ) - what do you wnat to do?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/c7pkb0h6/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are triggering baseFunction by calling `baseFunction(x)`. You need to either get `baseFunction` to return a function which can be executed:

```
// The class that we want to create an array of
myClass = function() {
    this.aFunction;
};

myClass.prototype = {
    // Add a new function to this class
    addFunction: function (newFunction) {
        this.aFunction = newFunction;
    },

    // Use the current function
    useFunction: function () {
        if (typeof this.aFunction === "function") {
            this.aFunction.call(this);
        }
    }
};

// The base function we will use in the classes
var baseFunction = function(x) { 
    return function() {
      console.log(x);  
    };
}

// Create the array of classes
var myClasses = [];

// Add 10 classes to the array and add a function to each of them
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    myClasses.push(new myClass());
    myClasses[x].addFunction(baseFunction);
}

// Use the function in the first class
myClasses[3].useFunction();
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytqnx2f9/)

Or add another parameter to addFunction which can be called like addFunction(baseFunction, x):

```
// The class that we want to create an array of
myClass = function() {
    this.aFunction;
};

myClass.prototype = {
    // Add a new function to this class
    addFunction: function (newFunction, value) {
        this.aFunction = newFunction;
        this.x = value;
    },

    // Use the current function
    useFunction: function () {
        if (typeof this.aFunction === "function") {
            this.aFunction.call(this, this.x);
        }
    }
};

// The base function we will use in the classes
var baseFunction = function(x) { console.log(x); }

// Create the array of classes
var myClasses = [];

// Add 10 classes to the array and add a function to each of them
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    myClasses.push(new myClass());
    myClasses[x].addFunction(baseFunction, x);
}

// Use the function in the first class
myClasses[3].useFunction();
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jscd2mj/)

Note I also changed your check for `aFunction == null` as the function passed in may be null, or a string, or anything else. You want to check if it is executable.

Comment: Thanks! I went with changing my base function to return a function since it makes activating it simpler, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
...
myClass.prototype = {
    // Add a new function to this class
    addFunction: function (newFunction, x) {
        this.aFunction = newFunction;
        this.aFunctionX = x;
    },
    useFunction: function () {
        if (this.aFunction != null) {
            this.aFunction(this.aFunctionX);
        }
    }
};
...

...
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    myClasses.push(new myClass());
    myClasses[x].addFunction(baseFunction, x);
}
...
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ra1rb74w/6/